# Excel 2010 shared workbook - image buttons disabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I have several Excel workbooks which were originally created in a 2007 version. 
They are shared workbooks, and contain some VBA code, and are protected to prevent users from changing certain content.

When opening them in Excel 2010, none of the image buttons work any longer. When unsharing the file and opening it in exclusive mode, the buttons work again. Sharing it again - buttons not working. Opening the same file in Excel 2003 or 2007 - no problem.

All trust center settings concerning ActiveX and Macros are set to fully enabled. The network location is set as trusted location. I get no Macro warnings when opening the workbook.

I found a few forum entries with this problem but none has replies with a solution.
(Note - this is NOT the Office update problem from Dec 2014.)

Edit:
The file is saved in Excel 2003 format as I need to support some Excel 2003 workstations.

Edit 2:
The buttons in question are "image buttons", i.e. I am using the Click event on an image ActiveX control. Regular buttons do not have this problem - they do work when shared.

Comment: What fileformat is your Excel sheet in? xls or xlsm? Try opening in 2010 (sharing diabled), save it in xlsm format, open it again, re-enable sharing en see if that helps.

Comment: Good idea. I realized I did not mention the file is in XLS (Excel 2003) format and I must support workstations which still have Excel 2003.

Comment: I have tried to save it as *.xlsm format. No change - I can click the button when unshared, but no action when the sheet is shared. Tried to add new image buttons - they do not work either. Regular buttons work - but not the Click() event on an image ActiveX control.

Comment: Hmpf. Too bad. Maybe try the official Microsoft Help fora? You're also probably entitled to product support... I don't have a clue. Sorry.